# MOSFET gets hot in an Op-amp MOSFET-based constant current load build

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet, electronic-load

I've made this schematic following the circuit steps in this [site](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/adustable-electronic-dc-load-using-arduino):

[image]

and after running the output with just 0.1-1A (which works ok according the input setting and current reading seems correct) but the MOSFET seems to get super hot and measuring the output voltage Vgs on the MOSFET, the comparator seem to be giving a low ~4Vgs max of the FET and probably not turning it fully on.

What should be done in this situation assuming not a lot of experience with comparators and such.

Comment: what is the voltage of Vin ? according to my understanding lm358 cant give more than (V+ - 2) on its output ..

Comment: You're asking it to sink a constant current -> it's never going to be fully on. By definition, this circuit has to operate in linear mode. If you MOSFET ever gets fully switched on, then you no longer have control over the current it's sinking.

Comment: Is your MOSFET heatsunk? The most you can reckon to dissipate with a bare TO-220 package is 2 W maximum, and running a FET in linear mode it would be best to stay well away from the maximum.

Answer (score 3):

This is a linear circuit so of course it isn't turning the MOSFET fully on when maintaining a constant current output.

That means it is dissipating power in the MOSFET. Measure Vds in operation (voltage between pins 2 and 3) and multiply by the current to see how much power you are dissipating.

By matching Vin and the LED string voltage you can reduce that power, but if you want to maintain CC regulation you can't eliminate it, so you have to deal with it using a heatsink.

How are you heatsinking the MOSFET?

Given a certain power - let's say 5W (5V and 1A) - you need a big enough heatsink to dissipate that heat without too high a rise in temperature. Heatsinks are rated in degrees per watt .. so a 5C/Watt heatsink would limit the temperature rise to 25C in our 5W example.

Without a heatsink, you can look up the MOSFET's own thermal resistance (junction to air) in its datasheet : it may be 60C or 100C per watt ... of course that's unsustainable at 5W dissipation. There will be a much lower resistance from junction to heatsink : maybe 1C/W, which you add to the heatsink's own resistance (giving 5C for a total 30C in the example)

The alternative is to abandon this approach and approximate constant current using a PWM controller, which is more complex, but wastes less power by switching the FET properly.

Comment: Yeah but using a mosfet device and the load disapator doesn't seem to be that much of an efficient use of component type and for some reason and the plan is to allow the device to have a rating of up to 100A for wires conductors and other mosfet testings.

Comment: 100A? Then see last paragraph.

Comment: Aight cool seems like were learning new stuff here but just to complete the puzzel do you have anything to read about that PWM DC load method some mokup scheme from google would be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate Id x Vds, then you get needed power dissipation. The MOSFET in you application works like a variable resistor, so you have to expect large power dissipation.